# Upgrading windows 8.1 to 8.1 pro using pro pack with media center

Tags: windows-8.1, windows-8.1-upgrade

I am unable to upgrade from windows 8.1 to windows 8.1 pro using pro pack with media center.
when i enter the key i get a message "This key won't work, Check it and try again, or try a different key".

To enter the key, I went to System, and clicked on "Get more features with a new edition of Windows" link,  and selected  "I already have a product key"

I have tried entering the key several times but i see the same message.

Comment: in order to install media center on Windows 8.1 you have to do what you did when you were running Windows 8.0.  use the Add Features mechanic within Windows.  Its suppose to work if it doesn't you should contact Microsoft.

Comment: after spending sometime on the Microsoft support websites i found the solution . we just  need to  reboot the system.

This is a windows 8.1 upgrade bug because the system message is wrong and the it does not prompt for a restart.

Answer (score 1):

after spending sometime on the Microsoft support websites i found the solution . we just  need to  reboot the system.

This is a windows 8.1 upgrade bug because the system message is wrong and the it does not prompt for a restart.

Comment: restart did nothing in my case

Answer (score -1):

In some cases you need to uninstall (or disable) the antivirus first:
http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows8_1-windows_install/new-activation-code-for-windows-81-pro-pack-says/df3d76fb-32a4-4d0b-8828-c737e6791ec2